# pattern or example for classes with multi-table sqlite database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm working on an Android app where the database continues to grow.

To assist with my database I have a MySQLIteHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and contains strings for defining the tables.  I have a dbDataSource class that handles the adding, deleting, reading and writing of the database rows.  And a class called dbDataRow that acts as a row of data.

When the tables both contained two columns with the same name (ID and Name), these classes worked fine because the methods in dbDataSource would typically require the table name, and the table name was variable in dbDataRow.  But now the tables contain a different number of columns with different names, I'm currently trying to make a decision whether I should duplicate the dbDataSource and dbDataRow classes (one for each table) or figure out how to make them work with very different tables

I'm looking for a pattern or example of data access classes for a database multiple tables within an app.

I'm not certain whether the actual code will help with this question, but let me know what you would like me to include, if anything.  Thank you for any help!

Edit: below is some of the code - Note, I changed the name of dbDataRow to dbData.  You can see in the CursorToDB_Row, that the columns need to be explicitly entered into dbData.  This won't work if the columns in the two tables are very different...

```
public class dbData {

    private long id;
    private String dbData;

    private String myTable;


    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dbData;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return dbData;
    }

    public void setDbData(String dbData) {
        this.dbData = dbData;
    }

    public void setTable(String myTable){
        this.myTable = myTable;
    }

    public String getTable(){
        return myTable;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDbData() {
        return dbData;
    }


}




public class dbDataSource {

    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_NAME };

    public dbDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    //Creates an DB entry by table name, a column, value for column, and the ID column, which it will
    //populate automatically
    public dbData createDB_Row(String comment, String myTable, String myColumn, String myIDColumn) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(myColumn, comment);
        long insertId = database.insert(myTable, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(myTable,
                allColumns, myIDColumn + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
            dbData newDbData = cursorToDB_Row(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newDbData;
    }

    //Deletes a DB entry by dbData, table name, and the ID column.
    public void deleteDB_Row(dbData dbData, String myTable, String myIDColumn) {
        long id = dbData.getId();
        System.out.println("dbData deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(myTable, myIDColumn + " = " + id, null);
    }


    //assumes ID is column 0 and the main string (usually name) is 1
    private dbData cursorToDB_Row(Cursor cursor) {
        dbData dbData = new dbData();
        dbData.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        dbData.setDbData(cursor.getString(1));
        return dbData;
    }


}
```

Comment: It is not entirely clear what functions `dbDataRow` and `dbDataSource`. Could you post the code that includes these classes?

Comment: There is no well-defined pattern. My recommendation is to have a different objects for different entities in your database (so I guess that means a different `dbData` class for each of your tables).

Comment: I've started doing a funky workaround. I'm keeping it as is, but am always supplying the myTable variable in dbData.  in dbDataSource I'm adding a private int get_Column_IntVal (dbData dbData, String myColumn) {..} and a private String get_Column_StrVal (dbData dbData, String myColumn) {...}. As long as I have a dbData object and know the column name, I can call one of those (depending on the data type) to get the column value.

Comment: Oops.  The above methods should have been written as public, not private.